# Is it possible to record the file execution order in a node / express project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, module

##### I'd like to see which file is executed before which file when running the program. and maybe log each file name in the console like this:

npm run dev ...

-> 1. src/index.ts

-> 2. src/model/something.ts

-> 3. src/lib/something.ts

-> ...

###### I could add a log function to every file, but I need to check many files.

Comment: Are you using commonjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-in-the-middle to add a callback handler that gets called whenever `require` is called (`require` is the function Node.js uses to load files), and you can log the file that gets `require`'d in this callback function.

If you're using ESM, you'd have to create a custom ESM loader hook (https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v18/esm/#resolvespecifier-context-nextresolve)

Comment: Yes, but this only works for CJS users.